# dynamically fill a jquery UI category autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, fill

I'm trying to fill a autocomplete jquery from the event of a select, but can not, I've tried several ways but no work for me because I'm not sure how we should pass the objects array, I tried this Walking away so simple:

```
$(".busqueda_asignatura").catcomplete("option","source"
    function(){
         $.getJSON("../Controller/CtrlPensum.php"{
              id_periodo: $("# id_periodo").val(),
              id_nivel: id_nivel.val(),
              autocompletado_asignatura: "autocompletado_asignatura"
         }).done(function(response){
         });
});
```

It may be a silly syntax error because i have no idea how fill the autocomplete  that way, I put in an alert the getJSON response and shows me the objects returned by the query

Comment: There should definitely be a comma after ...CtrlPensum.php" and before {

Answer (score 0):

You can try this javascript component ：
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js